# iphone crash on specific device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

My app includes scrollview/pagecontrol and get image from web and display on scrollview. It works fine on ipod 2nd Gen and Simulator but somewhat it crashes on Iphone 3GS. Apparently it crashes on

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] 
                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]
                            dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

this line. I have no idea what would cause to crash on it since it works smoothly on other device and simulator. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As always, we'll need to see a stack trace and console log output to make any headway in explaining a crash.  Please provide those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your traceback

```
NSString* myurl = @"http://example.com";
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString:myurl];
NSString* urlContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:nil];
```

I guess issue is not with the 2G and 3G.
the problem with your encoding use other encoding format for ex: NSASCIIStringEncoding

Comment: As i told you if you could tell us what was the traceback  error when you are running on other device, we could come with the solution.

Comment: it just gives sig fault(mostly access invalid mem address) without traceback.

Comment: Then it may cause with device when Memory corruption/overrun, A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system).                                       **what is the RAM of your iPhone 3GS and what iOS ?** It could have been better if you could share the screenshot of that error..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you specify the encoding of the `NSString` to be `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, but the data to be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` - try making both of these the same, and see if the error still occurs.